# Update form from shared event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I've got a form I've created with 4 `buttons` that will modify a `listView`, each with their own click event. I'm wondering as a way to avoid adding a method call in each of these buttons if it their is an event available for after a button has finished executing its click event?

The reason for this is so I can update the `listView` which will in turn update a `webBrowser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example which results in "1" and then "all" being displayed to the user when button 1 is clicked, "2" and then "all" when button 2 is clicked etc etc.

**Note:** you don't want to do it like this - see comments

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach(var b in Controls.OfType<Button>())
            b.Click += new EventHandler(AnyButton_Click);
    }

    void AnyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("all");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("3");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("2");
    }
```

Comment: Its as simple as just adding a second click event? How can I (Does this) guarrantee the order that these will get called?

Comment: @Sayse You really shouldn't, it would be bad practice to rely on the ordering of the event handlers (despite the fact that they do indeed have an order).  If you want to rely on it you should just call the common method at the end of each button-specific handler.  It will be much easier to maintain the code that way.

Comment: @Servy - Thank you for your advice.. the order these events gets called is imperitive to its function so I'll just bite the CopyNPaste bullet, thanks! Nathan accepted your answer since it did do what I was hoping to do..

Comment: Servy is right - this is just an example which addressed directly your question and isn't good code - you should code a function call at the end of each click event.